# Increment the last segment of a current URL when click on a button

Tags: javascript, php

## I have

a **btn**

`<button id="next" onclick="inlastSegment()">Next</button>`

and a **URL**

`http://localhost:8888/projects/oop/2`

---

## My goal

is when I clicked on that btn, I want to increment the lastSegment of my URL.

Example

- `http://localhost:8888/projects/oop/3`
- `http://localhost:8888/projects/oop/4`
- `http://localhost:8888/projects/oop/5`

I've tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var href = location.href; // http://localhost:8888/projects/oop/2
var lastSegment = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
console.log(lastSegment); //2

function inlastSegment() {
    lastSegment = (parseInt(lastSegment)+1);
    console.log(lastSegment); //3
    //Stuck
}

</script>
```

---

I'm a little stuck, any hints / suggestions will be much appreciated.

Is it even possible to achieve this in PHP ? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes. I want to go to that incremental URL, when I click on my NEXT btn.

Comment: _I want to go to that incremental URL.._ You have to use [`window.location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) method

Comment: Hm... okay. Let me try that.

Comment: I think you are going to add the pagination try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzp0dw83/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `location.replace` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pathArr = window.location.pathname.split('/'), lastSegment = pathArr.pop();
    function inlastSegment() {
        pathArr.push(++lastSegment);
        location.replace(pathArr.join('/'));
    }

</script>
```